# Floats in python

Tags: python, audio

I want to make a metronome. My code is:

```
import time
import sound

metronome = raw_input("")
int(metronome)

while 1==1:
  sound.play_effect('Drums_02')
  time.sleep(metronome)
```

When I run this code it comes up with an error message saying "A float is required."
I was woundering if anyone could make sense of it.

Comment: What is the full traceback of the exception?

Comment: By the way, you can just do `while 1:` or `while True:` rather than doing `while 1==1:`.

Answer (score 2):

`int(metronome)` does not convert `metronome` into an integer. It creates a new `int`, and then discards it because you don't do anything with it. You want to instead pass that along to your `sleep` call:

```
time.sleep(int(metronome))
```

Or, if you're using it in multiple places, assign `metronome` an `int` value in the first place:

```
metronome = int(raw_input(""))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int(metronome)
```

does nothing to the variable except for printing the int representation of the string.

You wanted to say:

```
metronome = int(metronome)
```

or

```
metronome = int(raw_input(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

`metronome` is still as string, not an integer. Store the result of `int()` back into the variable:

```
metronome = int(mentronome)
```